# Field extension is a smooth morphism between schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $L/k$ is a field extension. Is the morphism $\operatorname{Spec} L \to \operatorname{Spec} k$ a smooth morphism between schemes? If the field extension is separable algebraic then I suppose it is true. But I can't prove it as well as I don't know for general field extension. We can assume that all the fields here are of characteristic zero.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Recall that one definition of a smooth morphism is a morphism which is 1) locally of finite presentation, 2) flat, and 3) has geometrically regular fibers. Let's go through these criteria one by one.

- Locally of finite presentation: as both our schemes in question are one-point spaces, we must have that $L\cong k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/(f_1,\cdots,f_m)$ by the definition of locally of finite presentation. By Zariski's lemma, this means that $L$ must be a finite extension of $k$.
- Flat: since $k$ is a field, any scheme over $k$ is flat.
- Geometrically regular fibers: this says that $L\otimes_k \overline{k}$ must be regular. This happens exactly when $L/k$ is a separable extension: writing $k\subset L$ as $k\subset k_s\subset L$ with $k\subset k_s$ separable and $k_s\subset L$ purely inseparable, we have that $L\otimes_k \overline{k} \cong L\otimes_{k_s} k_s \otimes_k \otimes \overline{k}$. As the tensor product is associative, we can compute the right-hand tensor product first: then as $k_s$ is a finite separable extension of $k$, we may write it as $k[t]/(p(t))$ for some separable polynomial $p$ by the theorem of the primitive element. But then $k[t]/(p(t))\otimes_k \overline{k}\cong \overline{k}^d$, where $d=\deg p$, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Thus as tensor products commute with direct sums, $L\otimes_k \overline{k} \cong (L\otimes_{k_s} \overline{k})^d$. I claim that if $L/k_s$ is nontrivial, then $L\otimes_{k_s} \overline{k}$ contains nontrivial nilpotents: if $x\in L$ is an element with minimal polynomial $x^p-\alpha$ for $\alpha\in k_s$, then $(x-\alpha^{1/p})^p=0$ in our tensor product, but $x-\alpha^{1/p}\neq 0$.

Therefore a field extension $L/k$ is a smooth map iff $L$ is a finite separable extension of $k$. Since you're assuming that all your fields are of characteristic zero, this means that separability is automatic.